# How can I get the Material-UI DataGrid to read object data from an array?

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I'm currently using Redux to fetch data from an API.  I am then using this data to populate a DataGrid component from Material-UI.  Below is what the api response looks like:[image: API Response]

Below is what I currently have setup for the column definitions:

[image: Column Definitions]
[image]

The DataGrid seems to be able to recognize the id field from the results, as seen below, however, I cannot seem to drill down into attributes to get further details.

[image]

I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to display the attribute data, along with the id.  All help is appretiated, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`valueGetter`](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/columns/#value-getter):

```
const columns = [
  // ...
  {
    field: 'attributeName',
    headerName: 'Attribute Name',
    valueGetter: (params) => {
      return params.getValue(params.id, "attributes").name;
    }
  },
  // ...
];
```

You may also need a `sortComparator` to handle the sorting of this column.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue.  I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

try something like this to map the data out obviously change around the names as needed

```
const detailsRows = rows.map((row) => {
return {
  id: row.item_id,
  model: row.model_no,
  title: row.title,
};
```

and then pass it in to DataGrid like this

```
<DataGrid rows={detailsRows} columns={props.columns} pageSize={10}/>
```